# Does resume_from_checkpoint also make the trainer not go through the same data?

Tags: python, huggingface, huggingface-trainer

Would `resume_from_checkpoint={path_to_checkpoint}` just make the trainer go through the data again, regardless of whether it should be a new epoch? Or would it start from the point in the data at which it previously stopped?

I want to change the `save_steps` parameter in `TrainingArguments` in the middle of training and so I decided to stop the trainer and then let it run with the new `save_steps`. But I want to know whether the trainer also saves the information about which part of the training data it has already trained on.